# Get column from children as list in one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table called `forms` and one table called `categories`. They have a many-to-many relationship through a `category_form` as pivot. The pivot table has `form_id` and `category_id`

So each form can have many categories and every category can be attached to many forms.

I need to aggregate this data somehow. What I need is a comma separated list of category id's in a column for each form.

Like this:

```
FORMS
id  | name | categories 
1   | f1   | 1,4,7
2   | f2   | 1
3   | f3   | 1,6,8,9
```

What would be an effective way of doing this?

Comment: Please share table structure with sample data for forms, categories and category_form. And also please mention the version of mysql you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT f.id, f.name, GROUP_CONCAT(cf.category_id) AS categories
FROM forms f
INNER JOIN category_form cf ON f.id = cf.form_id
GROUP BY f.id, f.name
ORDER BY f.id;
```